# How do change only a path from image source with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to add dark mode function to my website and everything is fine with divs and other objects but I cannot change the only the path of images.

I have 2 folders for dark & regular images and each folder contains same files with same names but only edited for dark and regular mode of website, so I want to change the src to `../assets/imgs/regular/filename.jpg` to `../assets/imgs/dark/samefilename.jpg`.

I'm so much a newbie so please keep your answers simple.

Comment: Please post a reproducible example. So it will be easier for people to answer. You can also include a Codepen or JSFiddle if that suits you.

Comment: `$(img),attr('src', ' ../assets/imgs/dark/samefilename.jpg');` - simple example

Comment: i am so sorry i forgot to do that but problem already solved but thanks for warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to

- Loop over your images
- Pull each SRC attribute
- Do a regex find/replace

i.e. something like this for setting to dark mode:

```
jQuery('img').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).attr('src', jQuery(this).attr('src').replace(/assets\/imgs\/regular/i, 'assets/imgs/dark'))
});
```

Comment: I like your solution, although he can simply replace them by using the includes() method, and also revert pictures back to the light ones in the same way. I think that would be easier for him, since he said he is really new to JS, so I assume he doesnt know regular expressions yet :)

Comment: thanks a lot! this is exactly what i looking for.

Comment: You probably don't need a regular expression to be fair, they're just more fault-tolerant. `replace('/regular/', '/dark/') would suffice too.

Answer (score 0):

select the image tag, and change `src` attribute with Jquery `.attr()`

```
$("img").attr("src","your path");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with `jQuery` (although you can also do it with vanilla js), you should use `jQuery's attr()` function.

For example, if your image has an id of `myImage`, simply write :

$("#myImage").attr('src', '../assets/imgs/dark/samefilename.jpg');

This will change the path from your regular image to a dark one.

But I assume you also want it to revert back once you turn off your dark mode.

So adding `if-else` here is perfect. For example :

```
$("#darkModeButton").on('click',function(){

    if($("#myImage").attr('src') == '../assets/imgs/regular/filename.jpg'){

        $("#myImage").attr('src','../assets/imgs/dark/samefilename.jpg');

    }

    else {

        $("#myImage").attr('src','../assets/imgs/regular/filename.jpg');

    }        

}
```

This was just a dummy example, I assume you have more then one image that you want to replace with a dark one. :)

Hope I helped even a little bit.